# Time complexity for separate chaining and open addressing in hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

For a hash table using separate chaining with N keys and M lists(addresses), its time complexity is:

```
Insert: O(1)

Search: O(N/M)

Remove: O(N/M)
```

The above should be right I think.

But I don't feel comfortable analyzing time complexity for open addressing. Let's say the load factor is still N/M, can someone shed some light how to approach its time complexity and maybe also a little comparison of the two implementations.. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm particularly interested in linear probing here.

Comment: There are many different implementations of open-addressing (linear probing, quadratic hashing, double hashing, Robin Hood hashing, etc.).  What specific implementation are you referring to?

Comment: Linear one, just edited .. @templatetypedef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analysis of linear probing is actually *substantially* more complicated than it might initially appear to be.  The "classical" analysis of linear probing works under the (very unrealistic) assumption that the hash function used to distribute elements across the table behaves like a totally random function.  Unfortunately, this really isn't a fair assumption to make for most hash functions, since most hash functions distribute elements in a reasonably non-random way.  To pick a hash function for use in linear probing that has the (expected) time bound you gave above, you typically need to pick a type of hash function called a *5-wise independent hash function*.  This analysis is not simple, but if you're curious you might want to check out the paper ["Linear Probing with Constant Independence,"](http://www.it-c.dk/people/pagh/papers/linear.pdf).  This paper also does an analysis of linear probing hash tables with the assumption that you're using a weaker type of hash function to show why the above time bound won't hold in that case.

Hope this helps!